# OutOfMemoryException when passing camera picture to OpenCV

Tags: android, memory-management, android-camera

I'm capturing an image from the camera which I want to pass through some processing in OpenCV. On older devices, this is failing at the first hurdle though:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] jpeg, Camera c) {
  mImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpeg, 0, jpeg.length);
  org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat(mImageBitmap, Utils.cameraMat);
  ...
}
```

Produces:

```
04-22 14:23:41.708: I/System.out(7289): Available memory (bytes): 5646168
04-22 14:23:41.718: I/dalvikvm-heap(7289): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 51121168-byte allocation
04-22 14:23:41.758: E/dalvikvm-heap(7289): Out of memory on a 51121168-byte allocation.
```

Reading up about this, the advice seems to be to work with a smaller version of the image, but how do I work out roughly what dimensions to resize to given the amount of available memory left on the device?

Comment: On the official dev website, there is a whole chapter of the training dedicated to how to display bitmaps efficiently.

Comment: @Teovald Yes, but I'm not displaying this Bitmap at any point. I don't want to fit it to a size on screen, I just want to be able to pass the maximum number of pixels through to OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize your image before passing it to openCV. The decode instruction consumes a lot of memory because it loads the full image in memory. Even if you don't display it.

This [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) will show you how to resize your image without having to load it in memory first

Comment: I've read through this, but my problem is choosing the values for width and height. It's fine if I'm displaying it on screen and know exactly what these are in advance, but I don't in this case. How can I maximise them, knowing only how much memory I have available?

Comment: I don't think you can do it precisely. You could start from what you need from openCV instead.

Comment: Is there a way to do it safely? In OpenCV I need as many pixels as possible :-)

Comment: @TomMedley Have you considered for the very oldest generation of devices to either not support them at first or to process the pictures server-side? It might just be that those devices don't have the resources you need.

Comment: @badp The numbers above are taken from a Samsung Galaxy S II, currently the most popular device in most markets.

Comment: I remember Romain Guy (head of Android UI) saying that he generally considered the double of the scree  size was s

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how much memory your application has available to use, total, with [getMemoryClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29). You'll have to work out how much of that you're eating up with your application's other data, and the decoded bitmap above.

Some rough estimates:

The S II has an 8 MP camera. Assuming an RGB24 Bitmap, a single decoded bitmap will take up 8 * 3 = 24 MB of memory. The OpenCV matrix will probably take up about the same, possible more depending on what its internal format is (the out-of-memory error suggests it's trying to allocate ~48 MB, which is about twice the expectation here).

That's easily above what a standard app can use for memory - the minimum baseline is only 16 MB.  If you need more memory, you probably want to look into using a [large heap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap) instead of the normal-sized one. That will let you get roughly double the memory, although it's still device-dependent.